# c - sprintf() behaviour with argv

Tags: c, io, printf

This is a very simple question and mistake that I'm making but can anyone explain how I could use sprintf to add to a argv value?

On the command line, I have a file name say data.new.txt (but in my scenario I don't know the name of the file) how can I write to a new file that is named data.new.output.txt

I don't want to create a new file with a different name or update the new file, because this is program will output about 100+ files and that's the specification.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    char buffer[100];
    sprintf(buffer, "%s.decoded", argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Does the file name always have at least 2 dots? Find the position of the last dot and `sprintf()` from there.

Comment: No, it doesn't always have 2 dots

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C99 (it uses `snprintf()`) program for you. Have fun!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *buildname(const char *old, const char *newpart) {
  char *dot;
  char *buf = NULL;

  dot = strrchr(old, '.');
  if (dot) {
    size_t len;
    len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%.*s%s.%s",
                  (int)(dot - old) + 1, old, newpart, dot + 1);
    buf = malloc(len + 1);
    if (buf) {
      snprintf(buf, len + 1, "%.*s%s.%s",
              (int)(dot - old) + 1, old, newpart, dot + 1);
    }
  }
  return buf;
}

int main(void) {
  char *p, *q;

  q = "data.new.txt";
  p = buildname(q, "output");
  if (p) printf("%s ==> %s\n", q, p);
  else   printf("%s ==> (no dots)\n", q);
  free(p);

  q = "rrrrrrrrrrrr";
  p = buildname(q, "aaa");
  if (p) printf("%s ==> %s\n", q, p);
  else   printf("%s ==> (no dots)\n", q);
  free(p);

  q = "a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l";
  p = buildname(q, "Q.Q");
  if (p) printf("%s ==> %s\n", q, p);
  else   printf("%s ==> (no dots)\n", q);
  free(p);

  return 0;
}
```